# Python Одномерные массивы. Функции

Tags: python

> Известны данные о росте 15 юношей класса, упорядоченные по убыванию. Ни одна
> пара учеников не имеет одинаковый рост. В начале учебного года в класс поступил
> новый ученик. Какое место в перечне ростов займет рост этого ученика (известно,
> что его рост не совпадает с ростом ни одного из учеников класса, превышает рост
> самого низкого ученика и меньше роста самого высокого).

```
import.random
A=[random.randint(150,180)]
A.sort(reverse=True)
a=int(input('Введите рост нового ученика'))
```

не понимаю как выполнить все условия задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидно, что

1. в массиве `heights` у нового ученика будет позиция  `> 0`
2. в массиве `height` у нового ученика будет позиция меньше `len(heights) - 1`
3. поскольку у нового ученика рост не совпадает с ростом других учеников, то

а) надо пройти по массиву от `1` элемента по `len(heights) - 1`
б) если между соседними элементами разница больше `1`, то это может быть потенциальная позиция нового ученика

очевидно что таких мест может быть много